# Calculating the probability of a specific number of successful results out of a number of attempts, each with independent odds

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm attempting to calculate the probability of an exact number of successful outcomes in a set of unique scenarios that have independent odds. For example, I have 12 columns, each representing  scenario. There are 2 rows, 1 with the odds of a success, 1 with the odds of a failure for each attempt. What can I do to find the odds of any combination of 6 successes and 6 failures? Or the odds of 7 successes and 5 failures with 1 attempt of each scenario?

|  | scenario 1 | scenario 2 | scenario 3 | scenario 4 | scenario 5 | scenario 6 | scenario 7 | scenario 8 | scenario 9 | scenario 10 | scenario 11 | scenario 12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Success | .45 | .65 | .50 | .40 | .30 | .45 | .70 | .75 | .50 | .90 | .50 | .25 |
| Failure | .55 | .35 | .50 | .60 | .70 | .55 | .30 | .25 | .50 | .10 | .50 | .75 |

Ultimately, my goal here is to make a bar graph that shows the probability of a specific number of successes after going through each scenario once. The x-axis of this graph would begin by showing the odds of 0 successful attempts all the way through the odds of all 12 being successful attempts.

For example, I know my odds of 0 successful attempts after going through all 12 scenarios is calculated by multiplying the odds of failure for each scenario: =Product(.55, .35, .50, .60, .70, .55, .30, .25, .50, .10, .50, .75)= .003%

Once you throw in a few successes, it adds a lot more combinations of outcomes and I need to sum the products of each of the possible outcomes that would lead to exactly 3 successes.

I started by attempting to sum the product of the results of every combination of successes and failures manually but soon realized there would be 924 combinations for 6 successes and I unfortunately don't have that much time on my hands. Are there any tools or functions that I could use in Excel to make this a bit more feasible?

Comment: It seems to me it's a mathematical question, not an excel one!

Comment: Yeah, you're going to need to reach clarity on what you're trying to do, before you ask the question of how to use Excel to accomplish that. Excel can do arithmetic for you, but it can't reason wisely for you.

Comment: I'll also add that I'm not quite sure I fully understand what you're trying to do, and I'm not a probability expert, but I *think* what you might be looking for is known as a Monte Carlo Simulation. It's possible to set up a Monte Carlo Simulation in Excel, but neither Excel nor I can tell you whether or not a Monte Carlo Simulation is the right solution to your problem.

Comment: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/montecarlosimulation.asp

Comment: Thanks for the info, unfortunately, a Monte Carlo simulation won't work in this case because the probability of each individual attempt is already known and is not at the mercy of outside variables. I'll do my best to clarify the post

Comment: Start by figuring out the math needed, then we can help in applying it in Excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly identify there are 924 possibilities that result in 6 successes and 6 failures. Had the probabilities of success for each scenario been identical then you could have used the Binomial distribution (function BINOM.DIST) to calculate your required probability values. (Incidentally, your use of the term "odds" is incorrect. Technically, the odds of an event happening is the ratio of the probability that the event happens to the probability that it does not happen.)

Unfortunately, the fact that each of your scenarios has a different probability of success means that there is no easy way to calculate your probabilities using a built-in function. However, it is not too difficult to calculate your required values using Excel.

Possibly the simplest way is to recognise that there are 4096 distinct possibilities, ranging all 12 scenarios being failures to all 12 being successes. The 4096 arises because each of the 12 scenarios can be a success or a failure meaning that there are 2^12 = 4096 distinct outcomes possible. These 4096 possibilities can be represented by the integers from 0 to 4095 and each integer can be represented as a 12 digit binary number, with the 12 0's and 1's representing failure and success respectively of the 12 scenarios. The first challenge, therefore, is to  find a way of converting each integer to a set of 12 values of 0's and 1's. Any integer (say I1) in the range 0 to 4095 can be converted to 12 0/1 values as follows

- Calculate the first 0/1 value as MOD(I1,2), call result B1
- Calculate a new integer (say I2) as (I1 - B1)/2
- Calculate the second 0/1 value as MOD(I2, 2) and call this result B2
- Calculate a new integer (say I3) as (I2-B2)/2
  ... (continue these pairs of calculation steps)
- Calculate a new integer (say I12) as (I11-B11)/2
- Calculate the twelfth 0/1 value as MOD(I12/2), call result B12

For each integer I1 (taking possible values between 0 and 4095), the 12 values B1, B2,...,B12 represent the binary digits of I1 in reverse order.

It is fairly straightforward to represent this as a rectangular array of numbers in Excel with 4096 rows and 24 columns. The rows represent the integers 0 to 4095, the first 12 columns represent the values I1 to I12 and the second 12 the 0/1 values of B1 to B12, with 1's representing success and 0's representing failure.

A 25th column can be added with the value in each row calculated as the sum of the 12 0/1 values B1,...,B12 in that row. This 25th column simply identifies the number of "successes" corresponding to the row.

A further 12 columns (columns 26 to 37) can now be added representing the probabilities of each scenarios outcome. If Pi and Qi are the probabilities of success and failure for the i'th scenario then the probability value (say Vi) is simply (Pi×Bi)+(Qi×(1-Bi)). A 38th column can now be calculated for each row as the product (function PRODUCT) of the 12 values V1, V2, ..., V12 in that row. This calculated value represents the probability of the particular pattern of successes and failures arising.

The final part is simply to calculate the required probabilities of n successes (and 12-n failures) where n=0,1,2,...,12. This is simply the sum  of the values in column 38 for those rows where column 25 has a value of n (function SUMIF or SUMIFS).

If I have entered the probability data correctly into my workbook, I calculate that to 5 significant figures the probability of 6 successes (the original question) is 0.23788.

Comment: Thanks so much for this super descriptive answer! This is some really cool problem solving you've shared and I'm excited to give it a try. Thanks again for sharing, I really appreciate it!

Comment: There are other ways of converting what I have called I1 to the twelve 0/1 digits in the 12 digit binary representation of I1. The obvious choice is the DEC2BIN function but, alas, its first input argument is restricted to 511 (or 2^9 -1), so only directly useful for 9 or less scenarios. It could be made to work by splitting I1 into a 2 "digit" number to base 512 and then applying DEC2BIN to each "digit". Another possibility of applying DEC2HEX followed by HEX2BIN suffers the same difficulties as HEX2BIN has the same restriction of 511 on the first input argument.